# Rails, route time has to be greater than the time between two stops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need some help here with a restriction in Rails.
I created a transport site and the duration of the whole route should be greater than the time between two stops. This is my model file 'section.rb'

```
section.rb

class ValidatoreOffset < ActiveModel::Validator
    def validate(record)
        if record.controllo_offset
            record.errors[:base] << 'Error! Orario fermate intermedie maggiore dell orario della tratta di percorrenza'
        end
    end
end




class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :departures
    has_many :reservations
    has_many :stops
    attr_accessible :travel_time, :location_arrival, :type_of_section, :start_location, :id, :id_departure, :stop_id
    validates :type_of_section, inclusion: { in: %w(festivo feriale scolastico giornaliero)} , :allow_nil => false
    delegate :offset, :to => :stop, prefix: true, :allow_nil => true

    validates_with ValidatoreOffset

    def controllo_offset
        if section.stop.offset >= section.travel_time
            return true
        end 
    end

end
```

offset is an attribute of Stop that indicates the time between two stops.
What is wrong with that?

EDIT:
full error message:

```
Started POST "/sections" for ::1 at 2015-09-30 16:50:02 +0200
Processing by SectionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ywua04ZmGKKsv0OvkrealyAZ4s4iQ7IF1nFg41aYNpdtlXj9kPy4rRC/wkWzH5EoG+d23/QSvEhF4vdErkTNuA==", "section"=>{"start_location"=>"kbh", "location_arrival"=>"gfx", "type_of_section"=>"gfehmw,", "travel_time"=>"17", "stop_id"=>"6"}, "commit"=>"Create Section"}
Unpermitted parameter: stop_id
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)

NameError (undefined local variable or method `section' for #<Section:0x007f8a093691e8>):
  app/models/section.rb:23:in `controllo_offset'
  app/models/section.rb:3:in `validate'
  app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:29:in `create'


  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (20.5ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (12.8ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (27.2ms)
```

Comment: What is wrong with that? Does it raise an error? What is your problem?

Comment: it says "Undefined local variable or method 'section' for #<Section:0x......>

Answer (score 0):

When this method runs

```
def controllo_offset
    if section.stop.offset >= section.travel_time
        return true
    end 
end
```

it's running within a Section instance.  It doesn't know what "section" is - it just thinks it's an undefined variable or method, which is what the error is telling you.  You probably want to use `self` instead, which is the object which the method is running in.  eg

```
def controllo_offset
    if self.stop.offset >= self.travel_time
        return true
    end 
end
```

Comment: now it tells me 'undefined method 'stop' for #<Section:0x00...>

Comment: I'd expect you to know that an model has an instance method before you go and call that method on an instance.  i can't see your codebase so i don't know whether Section instances are supposed to have a `stop` method or not.

Answer (score 0):

As `controllo_offset` is an instance method, to access `Section` object you should use `self`:

```
def controllo_offset
  return self.stop.offset >= self.travel_time
end
```

And I think that `stop` method is wrong too, because you `Section` has many `stops`.

Comment: yes, it is.. but what should i put instead of 'stop' ?

Comment: I think you want `stops.last`. But you need to validate if section has at least one stop. I think you should take a time to understand how activeRecord works: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

your model should be. the `section` on accessing attribute in the model should be replace with `self` with in model

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :departures
    has_many :reservations
    has_many :stops
    attr_accessible :travel_time, :location_arrival, :type_of_section, :start_location, :id, :id_departure, :stop_id
    validates :type_of_section, inclusion: { in: %w(festivo feriale scolastico giornaliero)} , :allow_nil => false
    delegate :offset, :to => :stop, prefix: true, :allow_nil => true

    validates_with ValidatoreOffset

    def controllo_offset
        if self.stop.offset >= self.travel_time
            return true
        end 
    end

end
```